# Dynamically Add Values from Property

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract

I was wondering if I can dynamically add values set in property using override method. I want to add the values (scores) from properties so that in the end, I can get the total points.

here my code

```
public abstract class player
    {
        public string nickName { get; set; }


        public virtual int computeScore()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

public  class Bes : player
    {
        public int initScore =0;

        public int score { get; set; }
        public int ttlScore { get; set; }


        public override int computeScore()
        {
            return this.ttlScore += this.score;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Any exception or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Everytime i am putting data (bes1.score = 30), the value being returned by the computeScore is always the value that was recently entered. I was expecting to see the total score.
i tried it by entering 3 values. 

bes1.score = 10; 
bes1.score = 20;
bes1.score = 30;

The total score is 30;

i dont know what I should do.

Comment: What you should do is ADD to the score instead of ASSIGNING to it. Like `bes1.score = bes1.score + 10;`

Comment: Yes, but can I do the adding within the computeScore()?

Answer (score 1):

It's doubtful that want you want to do is a good idea. But the fact is, it's not really clear *what* you want to do.

I have a vague sense that you want, every time the `score` property is set, to add the value to the `ttlScore` property. If so, then sure...you can do that, but it's a terrible idea. Using a property to represent that operation would be extremely confusing; instead, you should have a method, e.g. named `AddScore()`, so it's clear reading the code that every time a score is passed to the method, it will be added to the running total.

For example, something like this:

```
public  class Bes : player
{
    public int MostRecentScore { get; private set; }
    public int TotalScore { get; private set; }

    public int AddScore(int score)
    {
        this.MostRecentScore = score;
        return this.TotalScore += score;
    }
}
```

Then the `MostRecentScore` property will still show whatever the most recent score was, while the `TotalScore` property will show the running total, but the class members make it clear that you must call `AddScore()` to report a new score, and that this will take care of updating both properties of interest.

This example of course does not use the `virtual` aspect of your code example. It's not clear from your question why the `computescore()` method was in fact made virtual, and it probably doesn't need to be — if you really want the base class to know about scoring, then the score-related properties belong there as well, and none of the members need to be `virtual` — so I've left it out.

If this does not address your question, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39602166/edit) so that it's more clear what you're trying to do. Provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a detailed and specific explanation of what the code does, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Thank you! :) Honestly, i really don't know what to ask. I just needed to add these scores using oop principles.

Comment: @KuysChan:  _"I just needed to add these scores using oop principles"_ -- that's a very vague requirement. Is this for a school assignment? If so, then your best resource is your teacher. They know exactly what concept it is they are trying to teach with this exercise, and can help you understand both the assignment, and its solution. There are many different ways a program could "add scores using OOP principles".